# Modifying the warning message when deleting an object in django admin?

Tags: python, django

I would like to add some stuff to the confirmation message on django admin ? The one that shows up and says "Hei, if you delete that you'll delete that and that and that too..."

Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django admin uses default messages framework https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/

to manipulate existing messages:

```
storage = messages.get_messages(request)
for message in storage:
    do_something_with(message)
```

to add new message:

```
messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'An info.')
messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'An success.')
```

To use this code, you will have to either override django admin views or create a middleware that will handle these messages. See this for overriding admin views:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view